# Maximal size for a child within a circle's sector

Tags: java, algorithm, user-interface, libgdx, scene2d

## Description

[image: Visual aid 1]
[image: Visual aid 2]
[image: Visual aid 3]

Given the following parameters:

- Outer radius
- Inner radius
- Amount of regions
- Starting angle (that second picture starts at 180 degrees)
- Angle drawn (that second picture draws a total of 320 degrees from its starting angle)

How does one calculate the maximal size of the Images to draw so that they remain within their sector? On the left picture, I'm just using a hard-coded value because I haven't specifically been able to think of a nice, general, mathematical equation for that.

More variables could eventually come into play, if I ever decide to expand my library even more. Things such as the width of the separators or of the circumference's outline.

---

## Code

This is what I use to draw everything but the children Actors:

```
/**
 * Takes care of drawing everything that {@link #layout()} didn't.
 * (Basically everything but the children Actors.)
 *
 * @param batch a Batch used to draw Drawables. The {@link #sd} is used to
 *              draw everything else.
 * @param parentAlpha
 */
protected void drawWithShapeDrawer(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {

    /* Pre-calculating */
    float bgRadian = MathUtils.degreesToRadians*style.totalDegreesDrawn;
    float tmpOffset = MathUtils.degreesToRadians*style.startDegreesOffset;
    int size = getChildren().size;
    float tmpRad = bgRadian / size;

    /* Background image */
    if(style.background != null)
        style.background.draw(batch, getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());

    /* Rest of background */
    if(style.backgroundColor != null) {
        sd.setColor(style.backgroundColor);
        sd.sector(getX()+style.radius, getY()+style.radius, style.radius-BG_BUFFER, tmpOffset, bgRadian);
    }

    /* Children */
    vector2.set(getX()+style.radius, getY()+style.radius);
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        float tmp = tmpOffset + i*tmpRad;
        drawChildWithoutSelection(vector2, i, tmp, tmpRad);

        /* Separator */
        drawChildSeparator(vector2, tmp);
    }

    /* The remaining last separator to be drawn */
    drawChildSeparator(vector2, tmpOffset + size*tmpRad);
}

protected void drawChildSeparator(Vector2 vector2, float drawnRadianAngle) {
    if(getChildren().size > 1 && style.separatorColor != null)
        sd.line(pointAtAngle(vector22, vector2, style.innerRadius, drawnRadianAngle),
                pointAtAngle(vector23, vector2, style.radius, drawnRadianAngle),
                style.separatorColor, style.separatorWidth);
}

protected void drawChildWithoutSelection(Vector2 vector2, int index, float startAngle, float radian) {
    if(style.childRegionColor != null) {
        if(style.alternateChildRegionColor != null) {
            sd.setColor(index%2 == 0 ? style.childRegionColor : style.alternateChildRegionColor);
            sd.arc(vector2.x, vector2.y, (style.radius+style.innerRadius)/2, startAngle, radian, style.radius-style.innerRadius);
        } else {
            sd.setColor(style.childRegionColor);
            sd.arc(vector2.x, vector2.y, (style.radius+style.innerRadius)/2, startAngle, radian, style.radius-style.innerRadius);
        }
    }
    drawChildCircumference(vector2, startAngle, radian, style.radius - style.circumferenceWidth/2);
}

protected void drawChildCircumference(Vector2 vector2, float startAngle, float radian, float radius) {
    if(style.circumferenceColor != null && style.circumferenceWidth > 0) {
        sd.setColor(style.circumferenceColor);
        sd.arc(vector2.x, vector2.y, radius, startAngle, radian, style.circumferenceWidth);
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm laying out those children:

```
@Override
public void layout() {
    float degreesPerChild = style.totalDegreesDrawn / getChildren().size;
    float half = (float)1 / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildren().size; i++) {
        Actor actor = getChildren().get(i);
        vector2.set((style.radius+style.innerRadius)/2, 0);
        vector2.rotate(degreesPerChild*(i + half) + style.startDegreesOffset);

        if(actor instanceof Image) { // todo: do this properly !
            actor.setSize(30, 30);
        }
        actor.setPosition(vector2.x+style.radius, vector2.y+style.radius, Align.center);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly so let me rephrase: do you mean what the maximum dimension for an icon could be that should fit completely into a segment like in your first example? That might actually not make much sense because the dimensions would differ between segments unless you're rotating the images (which you probably don't want to do). Afaik most libaries use a bounding circle, i.e. the icons must fit into a circular region of the image.

Comment: @Thomas You understood properly. And yes, the first image is the most relevant. The other two are just to show what the parameters might modify.

Comment: Well, in that case I'd suggest you go for the circular image region because you probably don't want to rotate the images and if they could be applied to any ring segment you wouldn't want to require the user to upload new images - and rotating the segments might make that even impossible. So you might want to rephrase your question how to calculate the maximum size of a circle filling a ring segment. From my understanding the segment could be reduced to a trapezoid whose sides are formed by the tangents at the inner and outer ring's midpoint and the 2 sides of the segment.

Comment: Here's some formula of how you could calculate that: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233465/isosceles-trapezoid-with-inscribed-circle

Comment: @Thomas animations *will* come in play eventually, including rotations. But that's a good start!

Comment: Isn't the Angle drawn redundant? isn't it 360°/N?

Comment: @MauricePerry Indeed. That function is Overridden elsewhere and its behavior uses that variable more times, if I recall correctly. The proposed solution integrates it as a parameter since it avoids recalculating it multiple times. Eventually, the class itself will just hold that value, but I'm not really at that point of trying to optimize the thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
/**
 * Used to estimate the radius of a circle to be constrained within the widget
 * according to the input parameters. Doubling the returned value would give
 * you the size of a contained Actor which would roughly fill most of its
 * sector, or possibly overflow slightly. It is suggested to adjust slightly
 * the returned value by multiplying it with a factor of your choice.<br>
 * It's basically the minimum between 3 different possible radius values
 * based on certain layout properties.
 *
 * @param degreesPerChild the amount of degrees that a child's sector takes.
 * @param actorDistanceFromCenter the distance at which the child Actor is
 *                                positioned from the center of the widget.
 * @return an estimated radius value for an Actor placed with the given
 *         constraints.
 */
public float getEstimatedRadiusAt(float degreesPerChild, float actorDistanceFromCenter) {
    float tmp1 = actorDistanceFromCenter * MathUtils.sinDeg(degreesPerChild/2);
    float tmp2 = getMaxRadius() - actorDistanceFromCenter;
    float tmp3 = actorDistanceFromCenter - getInnerRadiusLength();
    return Math.min(Math.min(tmp1, tmp2), tmp3);
}
```